# Why is my event propagation not stopping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-propagation

I want to stop click event from propagating to parent element.
This is the HTML code.

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; float: right" onclick="if (confirm('Continue?')) { jQuery(this).children().click(); }">
  <button style="float: right; pointer-events: none;" class="form-submit-bold btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-submit-password" name="op" value="Save Password" type="submit">Save Password</button>
</div>
```

And have attached this jquery event to button element from console

```
jQuery($0).on('click', function(e) {
  alert('hi');
  console.log(e);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now, when I click on the button element using `jQuery($0).click();` this alerts 'hi' but then again the alert which should have been triggered on clicking div is shown.
I want to stop this. Why is stopPropagation not working ?

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: What element is `$0` a reference to?

Comment: $0 is in reference to button element.

Comment: So this would be from the developer console?

Comment: @Srishty are you expecting the `stopPropagation()` call to prevent the `confirm` dialog in the `div` element from being shown?

Comment: yes @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: yeah, from dev console @shrys

Answer (score 0):

Remove `pointer-events`, setting it to `none` as I found is possibly a reason here

The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, **pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases**.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation()
  alert('hi I am child');
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; float: right;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="alert('Hi I am parent')">
<button>
hit me
</button>
</div>
```

See your Problem

```js
jQuery('button').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('hi');
  console.log(e);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; float: right" onclick="if (confirm('Continue?')) { jQuery(this).children().click(); }">
  <button style="float: right;" class="form-submit-bold btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-submit-password" name="op" value="Save Password" type="submit">Save Password</button>
</div>
```